# Json.NET serializes enum as string even with default settings

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am using Json.NET 7.0.1.

The [documentation](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationGuide.htm) says that

> `Enum` [is serialized as] Integer (can be the enum value name with StringEnumConverter)

In my Global.asax.cs, I specify the default settings as follows:

```
JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = (() =>
{
    var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
    settings.Converters.Add(new StringEnumConverter());
    return settings;
});
```

However, in certain situations, I want `Enums` to be serialized as integers, for instance when I build a JSON which is to be stored in the database.

Here is how I went about it:

```
public class JsonSerializedType<T> : IUserType where T : class
{
    private static readonly JsonSerializerSettings serializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings();

    public void NullSafeSet(IDbCommand cmd, object value, int index)
    {
        cmd.Parameters[index].Value = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value as T, serializerSettings);
    }
}
```

However, even in this case `Enums` are serialized as strings. I checked that `serializerSettings` has no `Converters` and its `ContractResolver` is `null`.

Why is that so?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is happening because [`JsonConvert.SerializeObject`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/JsonConvert.cs) applies the incoming settings *on top of the default settings*, by internally calling [`JsonSerializer.CreateDefault(JsonSerializerSettings settings)`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializer_CreateDefault_1.htm).  I don't know if/where this behavior is documented, but it's visible in the [source code](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/JsonConvert.cs).  Thus the default list of converters will be used *in addition to* the empty list of locally specified converters, meaning the default `StringEnumConverter` will get used.

You have a couple options to work around this:

1. [Construct the `JsonSerializer` yourself](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializer_Create_1.htm) without using the default settings:

   ```
   public static class JsonExtensions
   {
       public static string SerializeObjectNoDefaultSettings(object value, Formatting formatting, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
       {
           var jsonSerializer = JsonSerializer.Create(settings);
           jsonSerializer.Formatting = formatting;

           StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(256);
           StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
           using (JsonTextWriter jsonWriter = new JsonTextWriter(sw))
           {
               jsonWriter.Formatting = jsonSerializer.Formatting;
               jsonSerializer.Serialize(jsonWriter, value);
           }

           return sw.ToString(); 
       }
   }
   ```

   And then use it like:

   ```
   var json = JsonExtensions.SerializeObjectNoDefaultSettings(value, Formatting.None, new JsonSerializerSettings());
   ```
2. Supersede the default `StringEnumConverter` with one that does *not* serialize enums as strings, for instance:

   ```
   public class IntegerEnumConverter : StringEnumConverter
   {
       public override bool CanRead { get { return false; } }

       public override bool CanWrite { get { return false; } }
   }
   ```

   And then use it like:

   ```
   var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value, Formatting.None, new JsonSerializerSettings { Converters = new JsonConverter[] { new IntegerEnumConverter() } });
   ```

   The locally specified converter will be picked up in preference to the default converter.

Temporarily nulling out the [`JsonConvert.DefaultSettings`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DefaultSettings.htm) would be a bad idea since it would not be thread-safe.

Answer (score 2):

### **REASON**

The behavior we see here is by design, passed settings in `JsonConvert` methods are getting merged with provided `DefaultSettings`, Here is a small part of Json.Net source code from JsonSerializer class to demystify the situation.

```
 private static void ApplySerializerSettings(JsonSerializer serializer, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
    {
        if (!CollectionUtils.IsNullOrEmpty(settings.Converters))
        {
            // insert settings converters at the beginning so they take precedence
            // if user wants to remove one of the default converters they will have to do it manually
            for (int i = 0; i < settings.Converters.Count; i++)
            {
                serializer.Converters.Insert(i, settings.Converters[i]);
            }
        }
```

As we can see Converters are merged with provided Default ones albeit with higher precedence.

### **Solution**

We can take advantage of higher precedence of recently merged converters and prevent `StringEnumConverter` conversion.

```
class PreventStringEnumConverter : StringEnumConverter
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var type = value.GetType();
        var undertype = Enum.GetUnderlyingType(type);
        var converted=Convert.ChangeType(value, undertype);
        writer.WriteValue(converted);
    }
}
```

and the usage would be like:

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj,
        new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            Converters = new List<JsonConverter> {new PreventStringEnumConverter()}
        });
```